Preciso de uma ajuda com meu codigo, preciso testar ele para ver está funcionando. mas preciso de avanço de tempo e não consigo fazer!
 import time
        import threading
        from datetime import datetime
        from flask import Flask, render_template
        import os
        import smtplib
        from email.mime.text import MIMEText
        from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
        from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
        from email import encoders
        
        app = Flask(__name__)
        
        # Configurações de e-mail (SUBSTITUA COM SUAS CREDENCIAIS)
        EMAIL_REMETENTE = "a@gmail.com"
        EMAIL_SENHA = "oxoz plyg dqrd whlo"
        EMAIL_DESTINATARIO = "a@gmail.com"
        
        tempo_inicial = time.time() # tempo_inicial agora será fixo, não será mais reiniciado
    
    horas_totais = 0
    ultima_log_50h = 0
    
    @app.route("/")
    def index():
        return render_template("index.html")
    
    def enviar_email(caminho_arquivo):
        """Envia um e-mail com o arquivo de log em anexo."""
        msg = MIMEMultipart()
        msg['From'] = EMAIL_REMETENTE
        msg['To'] = EMAIL_DESTINATARIO
        msg['Subject'] = "Log de Manutenção - 500 Horas"
    
        with open(caminho_arquivo, "r") as arquivo:
            anexo = MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream")
            anexo.set_payload((arquivo).read())
            encoders.encode_base64(anexo)
            anexo.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= manutencao_500h.txt")
            msg.attach(anexo)
    
        try:
            server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)  # Use o servidor SMTP do seu provedor
            server.starttls()
            server.login(EMAIL_REMETENTE, EMAIL_SENHA)
            server.sendmail(EMAIL_REMETENTE, EMAIL_DESTINATARIO, msg.as_string())
            server.quit()
            print("Email enviado com sucesso!")
            gerar_log("Email enviado com sucesso!", "importante")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Erro ao enviar o email: {e}")
            gerar_log(f"Erro ao enviar o email: {e}", "importante")
    
    def gerar_log(mensagem, pasta="log"):
        """Gera um log da mensagem fornecida."""
        nome_arquivo = "contador.txt"
        if pasta == "importante":
            nome_arquivo = "manutencao_500h.txt"
        caminho_arquivo = os.path.join(pasta, nome_arquivo)
        mensagem_log = f"{datetime.now()} - {mensagem}\n"
        with open(caminho_arquivo, "a") as arquivo_log:
            arquivo_log.write(mensagem_log)
        print(mensagem_log.strip())
    
    email_enviado = False  # Variável para controlar o envio do e-mail
    
    def verificar_500_horas():
        global horas_totais, email_enviado
    
        # Verifica se o total de horas é múltiplo de 500 e se o e-mail não foi enviado ainda
        if horas_totais >= 500 and horas_totais % 500 == 0 and not email_enviado:
            gerar_log(f"Máquina chegou a {horas_totais} horas de uso, fazer manutenção!", "importante")
            caminho_arquivo_importante = os.path.join("importante", "manutencao_500h.txt")
            enviar_email(caminho_arquivo_importante)
            
            email_enviado = True  # Marca que o e-mail foi enviado
    
        # Se atingirmos um novo múltiplo de 500 horas, permite o envio de novos e-mails
        if horas_totais % 500 == 0 and horas_totais > 0:
            email_enviado = False
    
    def loop_log():
        """Loop principal que monitora o tempo e gera os logs simulando o avanço do tempo."""
    
        global horas_totais
        global ultima_log_50h
        while True:
            time.sleep(3600)  # Agora o sleep é de 1 hora
            tempo_decorrido = int(time.time() - tempo_inicial)  # Calcula o tempo decorrido desde tempo_inicial
            horas = tempo_decorrido // 3600
            minutos = (tempo_decorrido % 3600) // 60
            segundos = tempo_decorrido % 60
            horas_totais += horas  # Incrementa as horas totais com o cálculo do tempo decorrido
            horas_desde_ultimo_log_50h = horas_totais - ultima_log_50h
    
            # Verifica se o log de 50 horas deve ser gerado
            if horas_desde_ultimo_log_50h >= 50:
                gerar_log(f"O contador está funcionando há {horas_totais:02} horas e está funcionando perfeitamente.")
                ultima_log_50h = horas_totais  # Atualiza a última hora de log de 50 horas
    
            # Verifica se atingiu múltiplos de 500 horas e envia o log por e-mail
            verificar_500_horas()
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        os.makedirs("log", exist_ok=True)
        os.makedirs("importante", exist_ok=True)
        log_thread = threading.Thread(target=loop_log)
        log_thread.daemon = True
        log_thread.start()
        app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)

